# Duda acerca de la dependencia entre interfaces en UML

Tags: uml

Dada el siguiente diagrama de clases:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber si la asociación entre la clase **ConcreteA** y la interfaz **B** es correcta, dado que la interfaz **A** tiene una relación de dependencia con la interfaz **B** ¿No sería redundante?. Por otro lado, la clase **ConcreteA** declara un atributo del tipo de la interfaz **B** ¿Esto acaso no requiere que exista esa asociación entre **ConcreteA** y **B**?

A quien pueda despejar mi duda, gracias de antemano.